# Test::Unit : use multiple cores

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, process

I sometimes contribute to Rails core code but the fact is the test suite is really big and every time you have to run them it takes really long. I have a 4-core processor, is there a Test::Unit option to use them all and make the tests faster ?

Answer (score 0):

It is down to the test runner. For example in ReSharper 6 the test runner can run test assemblies (not individual tests) in parallel. There may be other runners out there that have similar abilities.